# Python: Building an Image grid

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm new in python, I want to load random images from a folder. i wrote this code for loading a specific image.

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os
root = Tk()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("9.jpg"))
panel = Label(root, image = img)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
root.mainloop()
```

Pycharm IDE gives me these error 
"cannot import name _imagingtk"
2) [errors which IDE pycharm is giving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqxsF.jpg)

can anyone help me.

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: I'll assume some Debian based repo, install this: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python-imaging-tk

Comment: also please consider using pillow instead of original PIL

Comment: @Borja i m using windows 10.